# postresql npgsql c# parameters not working

Tags: c#, postgresql

I've been googling/reading for hours and just coming up more and more frustrated.

Here's my code

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=" + Properties.Settings.Default.db_server + ";Port=" + Properties.Settings.Default.db_port + ";User Id=" + Properties.Settings.Default.db_user + ";Password=" + Properties.Settings.Default.db_password + ";Database=" + Properties.Settings.Default.db_database + ";");
conn.Open();
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT user_password FROM users WHERE user_initials = :value1", conn);
// Now add the parameter to the parameter collection of the command specifying its type.
command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("value1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Char));

// Now, add a value to it and later execute the command as usual.
command.Parameters[0].Value = initials.Text;
string userPass;

try
{
    userPass = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    MessageBox.Show(userPass);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

With a valid value in the text of initials it's only returning a blank result.  if I hard code the initials I get a result with text.

Comment: try using parameter with `@` symbol like : `"SELECT user_password FROM users WHERE user_initials = @value1"` and then add the parameter like `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", initials.Text);`

Comment: That worked... but 1. why did it work? and 2. where could I have found that?  I feel like there's a complete lack of resources on this beyond the manual (every damn tutorial is basic garbage imo).  sigh.  I feel like I should have never left mysql.

Comment: as much as I remember, the newer version of `NpgsqlCommand` supports parameters with `@` symbol,*(not really sure but I think it still supports parameters with `:`)*. See: http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/exampleprograms.html